# IllegalMonitorStateException calling wait() on a thread inside its run method (with no synchronized block)

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I order to ensure that the thread which is reading data from a socket is stopped when the socket closes (due to the fact `socket.isClosed()` doesn't work as expected) I wrote a "heartbeat" to check if the socket is still open. The method `startHeartbeat()` is called just before the BufferedReader starts reading the socket, and it only starts reading when `isClosed()` is false.

There are some synchronized methods in play here, but unlike other similar questions, the `wait()` call is not within one of the methods. Here is the essential code:

```
synchronized boolean isClosed()
{
    return closed;
}

synchronized void setClosed(boolean b)
{
    closed = b;
}

//We need to make sure that the socket is still online, to ensure the reading stops when the connection closes.
void startHeartbeat()
{
    Thread heartbeat = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    post(THUMP_THUMP);
                    setClosed(false);
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    setClosed(true);
                }
                finally
                {
                    try
                    {
                        this.wait(PULSE); //Exception here!
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                }
            }
        }
    };
    heartbeat.setDaemon(true);
    heartbeat.start();
}
```

THUMP_THUMP is just a constant string that is sent out (the `post()` method just writes the object out on a `BufferedWriter`) and PULSE is the time between beats.

I'm not sure why there is an `IllegalMonitorStateException` here, after reading various threads (I understand why *they* have the exception) and reading the API for the exception. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What does the API say?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It says the exception is triggered when the thread does not own the object that it is calling wait on. As far as I know, this thread does own the object, as the object is itself...

Comment: It doesn't say `it doesn't own the object`. It says `it doesn't own the object's monitor`. What is that monitor?

Comment: Well, I guess it would be the main thread or the thread that called the method then...

Comment: @J_mie6: Why would it? I think you've misunderstood what it means to own an object's monitor: it's all about `synchronized`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Yes - you're not synchronizing on the object you're waiting on. The [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) is pretty clear:

> Throws:
>   `IllegalMonitorStateException` - if the current thread is not the owner of the object's monitor.

It's important to understand that "owner of the objects monitor" basically means "is in a synchronized block using that object". A synchronized block acquires the relevant object's monitor at the start, and releases it at the end. From the [Java tutorial on synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html):

> Synchronization is built around an internal entity known as the intrinsic lock or monitor lock. (The API specification often refers to this entity simply as a "monitor.") Intrinsic locks play a role in both aspects of synchronization: enforcing exclusive access to an object's state and establishing happens-before relationships that are essential to visibility.
>
> Every object has an intrinsic lock associated with it. By convention, a thread that needs exclusive and consistent access to an object's fields has to acquire the object's intrinsic lock before accessing them, and then release the intrinsic lock when it's done with them. A thread is said to own the intrinsic lock between the time it has acquired the lock and released the lock. As long as a thread owns an intrinsic lock, no other thread can acquire the same lock. The other thread will block when it attempts to acquire the lock.
>
> ...
>
> When a thread invokes a synchronized method, it automatically acquires the intrinsic lock for that method's object and releases it when the method returns. The lock release occurs even if the return was caused by an uncaught exception.
>
> ...
>
> Another way to create synchronized code is with synchronized statements. Unlike synchronized methods, synchronized statements must specify the object that provides the intrinsic lock [...]

In your code, the current thread is *not* the owner of `this`, because you're not synchronizing - hence the exception. You *must* synchronize - remember that `wait()` will *release* the monitor, then reacquire it before returning.

As a side-note, I'd strongly recommend *against* using a `Thread` object's monitor for synchronization, waiting, notifying etc - code within `Thread` already does that, so your code and its code could easily interfere with each other. I'd recommend creating a separate object solely for the purpose of synchronization/wait/notify.

Comment: ok, I sort of understand a bit better now... if you call wait() outside of the thread itself (ie, in another thread) why is it not necessary to have it in a synchronized block?

Comment: @J_mie6: You *always* need a `synchronized` block somewhere if you're going to call `wait`, otherwise it *will* throw an exception. The block could be higher up the stack - the important thing is that the thread must own the monitor.

Comment: hmm, funny. I don't think I have ever noticed that before... maybe I've just never used wait since I first learned about threads (and therefore forgotten about it).

Comment: Or just use the concurrent classes that already do most of this sort of thing.